# How exactly virtualenvwrapper 'binds' to project directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Over the past couple of days I started using the excellent `virtualenvwrapper` by Doug Hellmann and while its feautures are mostly amazing I am struggling to make sense out of a couple of its commands.

[setvirtualenvproject](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#command-setvirtualenvproject) states that:

> The arguments to setvirtualenvproject are the full paths to the virtualenv and project directory. An association is made so that when workon activates the virtualenv the project is also activated.

What exactly does the author mean here when he says that the project is also activated? I can understand what 'activating a virtual environment' means but 'activating a project' doesn't make much sense to me.

Furthermore, what is this 'binding' that's stated in both

- [mkproject](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#command-mkproject)
- [setvirtualenvproject](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#command-setvirtualenvproject)

Apperently I am a bit confused over these concepts. Any insight would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the nice features about virtualenvwrapper is that it can separate your project directory from the virtualenv itself. The project dir contains your code only; the virtualenv contains Python and any third-party libraries. This makes for a much cleaner environment and easier-to-navigate project structure.

Binding a virtualenv to a project is just a matter of a hidden `.project` file in the virtualenv dir that points to the actual project dir. That means that when you do `workon myproject` in a project-enabled virtualenv, you are taken there, rather than the virtualenv itself.

Comment: for some reason, if I use 'mkproject', virtualenvwrapper will go to the project directory, but if I use 'mkvirtualenv', even after using 'setvirtualenvproject', my command line will not go to the project directory that I just setup with 'setvirtualenvproject', any idea on why that is?